# 'S3Hook' object has no attribute 'download_file' in AIRFLOW DAG

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-webserver

2023-02-05 11:32:43,293] {{taskinstance.py:887}} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): download_from_s3> on 2023-02-05T11:32:34.016335+00:00
[2023-02-05 11:32:43,299] {{standard_task_runner.py:53}} INFO - Started process 87503 to run task
[2023-02-05 11:32:43,474] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: s3_download.download_from_s3 2023-02-05T11:32:34.016335+00:00 [running]> 67c7842be21b
**[2023-02-05 11:32:43,555] {{taskinstance.py:1128}} ERROR - 'S3Hook' object has no attribute 'download_file'**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 966, in _run_raw_task
result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
return_value = self.execute_callable()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/dwnld_frm_awss3.py", line 12, in download_from_s3
file_name = hook.download_file(key=key, bucket_name=bucket_name, local_path=local_path)
**AttributeError: 'S3Hook' object has no attribute 'download_file'**
[2023-02-05 11:32:43,570] {{taskinstance.py:1185}} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.dag_id=s3_download, task_id=download_from_s3, execution_date=20230205T113234, start_date=20230205T113243, end_date=20230205T113243

Getting error of download_file

My code is

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.hooks.S3_hook import S3Hook
from airflow.contrib.hooks.aws_hook import AwsHook


# Function of the DAG
def download_from_s3(key: str, bucket_name: str, local_path: str) -> str:
    hook = S3Hook('my_conn_S3')
    file_name = hook.download_file(key=key, bucket_name=bucket_name, local_path=local_path)
    return file_name


with DAG(
    dag_id='s3_download', 
    schedule_interval='@daily', 
    start_date=datetime(2023, 2, 4), 
    catchup=False
    ) as dag:

    task_download_from_s3 = PythonOperator(
         task_id='download_from_s3',
         python_callable=download_from_s3,
         op_kwargs={
            'key': 'sample.txt',
            'bucket_name': 'airflow-sample-s3-bucket',
            'local_path': '/usr/local/airflow/'
         }
     )
```

Comment: The imports suggests that you are using older version of Airflow. What versions of Airflow and Amazon provider do you use?

Comment: Version : 1.10.9

Comment: You should install Amazon backport provider https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-amazon/  then import the hook as `from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook` Note that Airflow 1.10 is EOL for 2+ years, you should update Airflow version as soon as possible

Comment: I have already **included from airflow.hooks.S3_hook import S3Hook**
**from airflow.contrib.hooks.aws_hook import AwsHook** Because when I am including the **from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook** , getting the error Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/dwnld_frm_awss3.py] No module named 'airflow.providers'

Comment: How can I upgrade the airflow..can you tell me the steps

Comment: This means that you did not install the backport provider properly. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.1/howto/upgrading-from-1-10/index.html A full guide for the update

Comment: Yes, it got resolved with the higher version..thank you Kalif

Answer (score 0):

The imports suggests that you are using older version of Airflow.
You should install [Amazon backport provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-amazon) then import the hook as `from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook`

Note that Airflow 1.10 is end-of-life for 2+ years, you should upgrade Airflow version as soon as possible. To upgrade Airflow you can follow this [guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.1/howto/upgrading-from-1-10/index.html).